# formタグの入れ子とブラウザーの解釈

Tags: html

以下のような、formを入れ子にしたようなソースを書くと、「ページのソースを表示」で見ると、これと同じように表示されますが、DOM Explorerで見ると、以下のように、form2、form3が消えてしまいます。

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id = "form1">
 <input type = "text" id = "tb1">
 <form id = "form2">
 <input type = "text" id = "tb2">
 <form id = "form3">
 <input type = "text" id = "tb3">
 </form>
 </form>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、form1とform2の間に`<form></form>`を挿入すると、form2、form3は見えますが、`<form></form>`は消えてしまいます。

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id = "form1">
 <input type = "text" id = "tb1">
 <form></form>
 <form id = "form2">
 <input type = "text" id = "tb2">
 <form id = "form3">
 <input type = "text" id = "tb3">
 </form>
 </form>
 </form>
 </body>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この点について、どうしてこのような挙動をするのか、おわかりの方いるでしょうか。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

まず、「ページのソースを表示」で表示されるのは書いたままのHTMLであって、結果的にブラウザがどう解釈したのかは関係ありません。ブラウザが実際にパース処理を行い構築したDOMツリーが、「DOM Explorer」に表示されているものです。

さて、既に言及されているように、**form要素の入れ子は禁止されています**([§4.10.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element))。

じゃあそういうHTMLを読ませるとどうなるのか。HTML5では

- 閉じられていない form 要素があるのに `<form>` が現れたら無視
- 余分な `</form>` が現れたら無視

と規定されています([§8.2.5.4.7 The "in body" insertion mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody))。

これを踏まえて質問に書かれたHTMLを見てみましょう。

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id = "form1"> --- form1開始
 <input type = "text" id = "tb1">
 <form id = "form2"> --- form1が閉じられていないので無視
 <input type = "text" id = "tb2">
 <form id = "form3"> --- form1が閉じられていないので無視
 <input type = "text" id = "tb3">
 </form> --- form1終了
 </form> --- 余分な閉じタグなので無視
 </form> --- 余分な閉じタグなので無視
 </body>
 </html>
```

結果として `#form1` に全ての input が収まります。

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id = "form1"> --- form1開始
 <input type = "text" id = "tb1">
 <form> --- form1が閉じられていないので無視
 </form> --- form1終了
 <form id = "form2"> --- form2開始
 <input type = "text" id = "tb2">
 <form id = "form3"> --- form2が閉じられていないので無視
 <input type = "text" id = "tb3">
 </form> --- form2終了
 </form> --- 余分な閉じタグなので無視
 </form>
 </body>
```

結果として `#form1` に `#tb1` が、`#form2` に `#tb2` `#tb3` が収まります。

Answer (score 3):

`form` タグの中にほかの `form` を入れてはいけません。W3 標準に[こう書かれています](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

> `form`
>   must not contain other `form` elements.

データの一部を送信したいなら、要素からデータを取り出して、Ajax で送信することをおすすめします。